# Disable Wagtail 5.1 audit log from appearing in console output?

Tags: wagtail

Since upgrading to Wagtail 5.1, it seems that the Wagtail audit log actions are being printed to the development console. This is very noisy and is interfering with other important log messages and progress indicators.

> Unpublished: "Page One" pk=282
>
> Page deleted: "Page One" id=282
>
> Creating redirects for page: 'Windward Oahu Worship Group' id=3471
> 1/1 redirects were created successfully.
>
> Page moved: "West Side Worship Group" id=3432 path=/welcome/community/meetings/intermountain-yearly-meeting/mountain-view-friends-meeting/west-side-worship-group/

How can I disable the Wagtail 5.1 audit log console output?

I tried searching the documentation for a configuration flag where I could tell Wagtail to disable console logging.